Highlighted dates are not following the Selected DateRange after Reverting the DateRangePicker Component to default values
I have implemented a DateRangePicker component in my app, from the Material-3 library.
Everything works fine, but when I press a button called ClearFilters and I reset the selected dates in the component using LaunchEffects by ovewritting the current dateRangePickerState with a new one which has the same arguments as the default/starting one I encounter a problem .
The highlighted date range between the selected Dates does not change place and remains in the selected DateRange before I pressed the clear filters button. After the first press, as many times as I press the button again or manually select new date ranges the highlighted date range does not move form that DateRange.
ClearFilters has not been pressed yet and the DateRangePicker works
ClearFilters Button was just pressed
Manually selected new DateRange after the ClearFilters has been pressed
I have created this DateRangePicker Component : This is the UserHomeScreen
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DateRangePicker(
    dateTime: LocalDateTime,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
    input: Boolean = false, //NOT USED NOW
    onDateSelected: (String?, String?) -> Unit,
    small: Boolean = false,
    clearFilters: MutableState<Boolean>?
) {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
    val displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy")
    var dateRangePickerState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(DateRangePickerState(
            initialSelectedStartDateMillis = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
            initialDisplayedMonthMillis = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
            initialSelectedEndDateMillis = dateTime.plusDays(3).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
            initialDisplayMode = if (input) DisplayMode.Input else DisplayMode.Picker, // ALWAYS PICKER AS OF NOW
            yearRange = (dateTime.year .. dateTime.year + 1)
        ))
    }
    // For the ClearFilters Button to work on the DateRangePicker in the UserHomeScreen
    LaunchedEffect(clearFilters?.value) {
        if (clearFilters?.value == true) {
            dateRangePickerState = DateRangePickerState(
                initialSelectedStartDateMillis = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
                initialDisplayedMonthMillis = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
                initialSelectedEndDateMillis = dateTime.plusDays(3).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(),
                initialDisplayMode = if (input) DisplayMode.Input else DisplayMode.Picker, // ALWAYS PICKER AS OF NOW
                yearRange = (dateTime.year .. dateTime.year + 1)
            )
            clearFilters.value = false
            Log.d("DateRangePicker", "Clearing DateRangePicker")
        }
    }

    if (small) { // For UserHomeScreen
        DateRangePicker(
            state = dateRangePickerState,
            showModeToggle = false,
            title = null,
            headline = null,
            dateValidator = { date ->
                val localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
                localDate.isAfter(dateTime.toLocalDate().minusDays(1))
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .fillMaxWidth(1.0f) // Fill 100% of the available width
                .size(300.dp, 200.dp) // Set the size of the DateRangePicker
        )
        Log.d("DateRangePicker", "Small DateRangePicker-EXECUTED")
    } else { // For BookingScreen
        DateRangePicker(
            state = dateRangePickerState,
            showModeToggle = false,
            title = { Text(text = " Choose Your Stay:") },
            headline = {
                val startDate = dateRangePickerState.selectedStartDateMillis?.let {
                    Instant.ofEpochMilli(it).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
                }
                val endDate = dateRangePickerState.selectedEndDateMillis?.let {
                    Instant.ofEpochMilli(it).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
                }
                if (endDate != null && startDate != null) {
                    val checkInDate = startDate.format(formatter)
                    val checkOutDate = endDate.format(formatter)
                    onDateSelected(checkInDate, checkOutDate)
                    Text("${startDate.format(displayFormatter)} - ${endDate.format(displayFormatter)}", maxLines = 1, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    Log.d("DateRangePicker", "Check-in: $checkInDate, Check-out: $checkOutDate")
                }
            },
            dateValidator = { date ->
                val localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
                localDate.isAfter(dateTime.toLocalDate().minusDays(1))
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        )
    }
}

I call this component in the UserHomeScreen like this :
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
val clearFilters = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedStartDateText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var selectedEndDateText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            // DateRangePicker
            Row {
                DateRangePicker(
                    dateTime = dateTime,
                    focusRequester = focusRequester,
                    small = true,
                    clearFilters = clearFilters,
                    onDateSelected = { checkIn, checkOut ->
                        selectedStartDateText = checkIn ?: selectedStartDateText
                        selectedEndDateText = checkOut ?: selectedEndDateText
                    }
                )
            }

The ClearFilters Button is implemented like this in the UserHomeScreen:
                // Add a button to clear search filters
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        // Clear the search filters
                        searchQuery.value = ""
                        selectedStartDateText = ""
                        selectedEndDateText = ""
                        selectedArea.value = "Athens"
                        selectedGuests = 1
                        selectedRatingState.value = 0
                        clearFilters.value = !clearFilters.value
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Clear Filters")
                }

If you have read this far down, thank you for your help, and I am sorry for the bad post. I am new to JetpackCompose and this is my first post on StackOverflow. Thank you for your understanding.
I have tried various suggested solutions from copilot, as I was not able to find anything on Google. Something about using derivedStateOf , which did not work obviously.
